# How to turn off colors for a specific command?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, colors

Is it possible to turn off colors for a specific command like `ls`, but without using the api of the command itself? Is there an env variable kind of thing that will turn off coloring for a command like doing `COLOR=off ls`? Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Edit: I want a general solution that will be applicable to all commands. like `COLOR=off command_name`

Comment: Read `man ls`. GNU `ls` has the `--color=never` option, and there's the `LS_COLORS` variable.

Comment: Do add on to @waltinator's comment, you could in your shell config file have something like `alias ls='ls --color=never'`

Comment: [This question shows how to remove color codes through the use of text replacement.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped)

Comment: At least on GNU/Linux systems, `ls` output is typically only colored in a terminal because `ls` is aliased to something like `ls --color=auto`. So to get uncolored output it is sufficient to prevent alias expansion ex. `\ls`. See also [How to turn off color with `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107371/how-to-turn-off-color-with-ls)

Comment: My question wasn't specific to `ls`. I want a general solution that will turn off colors for a command

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to allow some changes in the formatting, you may as well just pipe it through `cat`

```
 ls | cat
```

No colours, but newline for each entry.

---

Edit:

**Turning off colors via the shell settings**

Check your shell's rc file(s) and see where colors are set, then make a new `.<shell>rc_mono` where these settings are removed, source it and done. E.g. for bash:

```
$cat ~/.bashrc_mono
export TERM=xterm-mono
. ~/.bashrc
alias ls='ls --color=none'
alias grep='grep --color=none'
```

Note that `. ~/.bashrc` must precede the new aliases for `ls` and `grep` as their coloring usually is set in `~/.bashrc`.
So all you need to do is

```
. ~/bashrc_mono ; ls
```

Accordingly a "redo colors"-rc might be nice:

```
$cat ~/.bashrc_recolorize
export TERM=xterm-256color
. ~/.bashrc
```

Use e.g. `htop` and you will see the difference.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check it out.

Comment: @KMABadshah This answer is not specific for `ls` but should work for all commands that automatically switch on colors if the output goes to a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to set the `TERM` variable to a terminal type that doesn't support colors.

Examples:

```
TERM=dumb ls
TERM=dumb command_name
echo foo | TERM=dumb grep --color o
```

Telling the programs to use a dumb terminal might also have other (unwanted) effects depending on the command you run, for example `vi` may no longer recognize the cursor keys.

As suggested by [FelixJN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/123460/felixjn) you can also try `TERM=xterm-mono`, but on my test system (Git bash on Windows) this doesn't suppress colors in contrast to `TERM=dumb`.

Comment: `TERM=xterm-mono` is not as dumb as `TERM=dumb` - at least for cursors in `vim`. PS: beat me with the TERM-setting option, though specifying it specifically for the command is better than a new `rc`-file.